# Pass data from controller to view without calling the controller in url CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a Controller called Stats which is responsible to get some stats and show them in my application.

Stats.php:

```
<?php

class Stats Extends CI_Controller{

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->model('Stats_model');
    $return['users'] = $this->Stats_model->get_users();
    $return['photos'] = $this->Stats_model->get_photos();
    $return['members'] = $this->Stats_model->get_members();
    $this->load->view('stats',$return);
  }
}
```

In my application i have 3 total views with their controllers. Home,About,Contact - Home_controller, About_controller, Contact_controller.

In start of any of these 3 views i have a section which i want to place the the stats. So the stats will be visible in any page of my application.

How can i load a view (stats) to take data from a controller (Stats) without calling it? When the home view called then the Home controller called , NO the stats.

I don't want to call a separate stats page. I want the stats to be visible in top of any page in my app. How can i achieve that in CI?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize CI_Controller by adding `MY_Controller` in directory `./application/core/` and move the codes in Stats controller into it's constructor
like:

```
<?php

class MY_Controller Extends CI_Controller
{

    protected $_stat_view;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->model('Stats_model');
        $return['users'] = $this->Stats_model->get_users();
        $return['photos'] = $this->Stats_model->get_photos();
        $return['members'] = $this->Stats_model->get_members();
        //specify true to view's third parameter will make it return 
        //view content instead of render and display it on browser 
        $this->_stat_view = $this->load->view('stats',$return, true);
    }
}
```

And then your Home,About,Contact controller need extends this new `MY_Controller`

```
<?php
class Home_Controller extends MY_Controller
{
     public function __construct()
     {
          parent::__construct();
     }

     public function index()
     {
          $data[stats_section] = $this->_stat_view;
          //In home view just echo $stat_section
          $this->load->view('home', $data);
     }
}
```

FYI you can modify prefix `MY_` in `./application/config/config.php`, set what prefix name you like to config item `$config['subclass_prefix']`.